# Why is typeahead-focus-first="scopeVariable" is not updating uib-typeahead?

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I have used the uib-typeahead directive as follows :

```
<input type="text" id="search-box" class="form-control" data-ng-model="searchBar.search.searchString" 
    typeahead-on-select="searchBar.gotoPartDetails($item, $model, $label, $event)" uib-typeahead="result as result.partNumber+' '+result.lineDesc+' '+result.partDesc for result in searchBar.textTyped($viewValue)" 
    placeholder="Search by part number, product type, product line, keyword" typeahead-focus-first="searchBar.search.firstSelect" typeahead-popup-template-url="app/components/header/search-bar/typeahead-popup.html" typeahead-template-url="{{searchBar.search.typeaheadTemplate}}"
    data-ng-focus="searchBar.focus()" data-ng-blur="searchBar.blur()">
```

I am basically using the "`searchBar.search.firstSelect`" scope variable to enable or disable first select. On controller load `searchBar.search.firstSelect` is set to false and based on the size of the length data displayed. If the typeahead is showing just one data in the options  I am setting `searchBar.search.firstSelect` to true. But this is not reflecting in the UI. What do I do?

Comment: I'm also trying to conditionally set this value so that if a user types in "ABC" and hits tab, it'll select "ABC Corporation", but if they're just tabbing through the form, it won't automatically select a value.

Comment: Yeah this has a lot of use-cases. I wish they had made it dynamic.

Comment: FYI, edits to the Typeahead library are easy, I was able to fork and tweak the project to allow focus on first if the user has entered any value into the field: https://github.com/peder/bootstrap/commit/7c3e82be1a30285b55ec8a45e536a7553738e1ad You could also add a watch on the typeaheadFocusFirst attr if you needed the value to be dynamic